# active record create using attr_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, attr-accessor

I would like to use attr_accessor to create my active record. But it seems that it is not possible to do it. Is there anythings in ruby like this or is it a good practice? `User.create(:someattr => "halo")`?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :someattr
   after_create :do_sth

   def do_sth
       #do somethings depends on someattr
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

in the user model

when u create user object

```
user = User.new 
user.someattr = true
user.save!
```

In the User model change the after_create to before_create :do_sth

```
def do_sth
 if self.someattr 
  self.first_name = 'do_something'
  # You can implement the logic u want 
 end
end
```

Comment: is it possible to use User.create(:someattr=>true) instead of user.someattr = true and user.save!